# Find ActivityId of completed activity in AWS SWF?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am fairly new to SWF in AWS.
I am creating a workflow and am having a hard time figuring out how to identify the name of the activity that just completed. The decider needs to know this so that it can determine which activity to schedule next.

ActivityTaskCompletedEventAttributes (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ActivityTaskCompletedEventAttributes.html) don't include information about the id or name of the activity that just completed.

On the other hand, ActivityTaskScheduleEventAttributes (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ActivityTaskScheduledEventAttributes.html) does include this information.

When identifying the ActivityId and name of the activity that just reported completion, is it typical to just go back in the event history and get the id and name of the last activity that was scheduled (and assume that's the one that's reporting completion)? That doesn't seem right to me.

In the docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-dev-deciders.html#swf-dg-coordination-logic) they talk about defining coordination logic in a way that seems to have awareness of the name of the previously completed activity's name.

How is this actually accomplished in practice?

- Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for a while I came to the conclusion that the best way to handle this is basically by crawling back through the the event history list to find when the task was scheduled. The scheduled event contains the information I'm looking for.

Steps might look something like this:

1) Ensure you have loaded all history event pages a la the nextPageToken description here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_PollForDecisionTask.html#API_PollForDecisionTask_RequestSyntax

2) The link between ActivityTaskCompleted and the name of the activity that was completed is as follows:

ActivityTaskCompletedEventAttributes.ScheduledEventId =>
ActivityTaskScheduledEventAttributes.ActivityType.Name

In C# this might look something like

```
var name = eventHistory
                .Find(e => e.EventId == mostRecentEvent
                                            .ActivityTaskCompletedEventAttributes
                                            .ScheduledEventId)
                .ActivityTaskScheduledEventAttributes
                .ActivityType
                .Name
```

Where `eventHistory` is the list of history events supplied to the decider by SWF, and `mostRecentEvent` is the ActivityTaskScheduledEvent that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same problem about an hour ago so it's good to see you've found a solution. It's a bit of an odd design decision, isn't it? I get the logic behind this (i.e. if your decider is splitting large tasks into batches) but in most cases surely you'll want to transition from one task to another.

Comment: Agreed. I see the point also of not putting new properties on objects if the data can be found elsewhere (ie: don't include actor name in completed event if it's available in the scheduled event), but it's definitely not very handy.